# For a differentiable function $f$ , does this mean value theorem iteration method converge to the root of $f?$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, newton-raphson, mean-value-theorem

Suppose $a<b,\quad f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable, nowhere-linear function$,\ f(c)=0 $ for some $c\in (a,b),\quad$ and $f'(x)\neq 0\ \forall\ x\in (a,b).\ $ Let $x_0=a;\ x_1=b.$ *Nowhere-linear* means $\ \not\exists\ t_1,t_2\ $ with $\ a\leq t_1 < t_2 \leq b\ $ s.t. $\ f(u) = \frac{(f(t_2)-f(t_1))(u-t_1)}{t_2-t_1} + f(t_1)\ \forall\ u\in (t_1,t_2);$ more colloquially, $ f$ is not a straight line on any interval.

For every $n\in\mathbb{N},$

1. Let $ x_{n+1}$ be *any* point in the interval $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ such that $\ f'(x_{n+1}) = \frac{f(x_n) - f(x_{n-1})}{x_n - x_{n-1}}.$
2. If $f(x_{n+1})f(x_n)>0$
   discard $x_n$ and relabel $x_{n-1}$ as $x_n.$

> Prove or disprove: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = c.$

If yes, I would be interested to determine the rate of convergence for this method, and also if this method is of any practical use compared to Newton-Raphson. But the question is hard enough as it is, so let's tackle this question first.

Also, if we changed the first condition to, " 1. *We are allowed to choose any* $ x_{n+1}$ *in the interval* $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ *with the property that* $\ f'(x_{n+1}) = \frac{f(x_n) - f(x_{n-1})}{x_n - x_{n-1}}$ *that we like*," then this makes the question easier, because we can choose $x_{n+1}$ as close to the root as possible, although even then I don't know how to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = c.$

Also, I wonder if either of these methods are some sort of Newton-Raphson in disguise?

Comment: @MartinR responding to your first comment, I thought someone would say that. The difference is that in the first question, it is asking if convergence is guaranteed for *all* choices of $(x_n).$ The second question is asking if there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges. So I probably should have asked them the other way round. In any case, your second comment is correct and more troubling, and I am thinking now how to salvage the question. I think I left out some conditions in the original question.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now what you mean. Btw, this method reminds me more of the [secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) than Newton's method.

Comment: @MartinR Right! I wasn't aware of the Secant method. (Or maybe I was about $15$ years ago but completely forgot about it).

Comment: Is the question reasonable now? Or are there still trivial counter-examples?